# div to scroll rather than hiding after removing class on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with a fixed class which is removing fine on scroll.

I've been trying to get the div to continue scrolling after the fixed class has been removed but it keeps getting hidden rather than continuing scrolling

If anyone could advise / point me in the right direction that would be great

pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpjZEL

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $('.content').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="content fixed">
    <h1>content</h1>
    <p>Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam
      non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: the toggle would've worked if you'd just put a top value on the content css.  But here's an alternative (neater) pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZaxmV  No need for the margin-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove class `.fixed`, you're not just removing the `position: fixed` declaration, you're **also** removing the `top` and `width` declarations. You simply need to apply these back to `.content` after removing the class. Note that the element defaults to `position: relative`, so `top` will no longer work. As such, you'll need to use `margin-top` instead:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $('.content').removeClass('fixed');
    $('.content').css('margin-top', '550px'); // 50px covers the additional scroll
    $('.content').css('width', '30%');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="content fixed">
    <h1>content</h1>
    <p>Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam
      non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I've also created a new CodePen showcasing this [here](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/qrXKNg).

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**:

In order to have it go back to how it was when the user scrolls back up, simply use an `else` condition to undo the changes made by the `if` condition:

```
else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 500) {
  $('.content').addClass('fixed');
  $('.content').css('margin-top', '0');
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $('.content').removeClass('fixed');
    $('.content').css('margin-top', '550px');
    $('.content').css('width', '30%');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 500) {
    $('.content').addClass('fixed');
    $('.content').css('margin-top', '0');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="content fixed">
    <h1>content</h1>
    <p>Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam
      non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I've update the pen to reflect this, and it can still be found [here](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/qrXKNg).

Note that you may need to play around with the `margin-top` value of `550px` value in order to get a truly smooth transition :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Brilliant thanks, how can i get this to work with scrolling up as well as scrolling down? thanks

Comment: @S.B -- Assuming by "*work with scrolling up*" you mean return it to how it was before scrolling down, that's certainly possible. I've just updated the answer to cover this :)

Comment: there is a basic flaw in your pen, in that you keep the width at 30% even after 500 pix scrolling. As it is indicated that this needs to be removed after 500px, it seems that this is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: I thought that **was** the desired behaviour, although if the OP wants to remove this, simply add `$('.content').css('width', 100%');` to the `else` condition :)

Answer (score 0):

Your codepen works as-is. The reason it appears to disappear is because there is hardly any **content** in the `paragraph`. When i added more text in the paragraph and tried the code as-is again, it worked fine.

See for yourself http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWveaX

Snippet exhibits the toggleClass

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $('.content').toggleClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top:0px!important;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="content fixed">
    <h1>content</h1>
    <p>Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam
      non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis.
      Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel
      a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur
      semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis.
      Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis.
      In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus
      sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor.
      Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi
      eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet. Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula
      aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra.
      Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium
      dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros
      eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae
      eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus
      mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam
      feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut
      arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim
      eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam
      volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula.
      Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper
      dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis.
      Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis.
      In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus
      sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor.
      Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi
      eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula
      aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra.
      Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium
      dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros
      eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae
      eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus
      mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet. Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi.
      Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec
      ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non
      enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis.
      Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel
      a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur
      semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis.
      Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet. Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis.
      In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus
      sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor.
      Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet.Donec ut arcu quis enim vehicula aliquam vel a ligula. Nulla sagittis eros eu molestie mattis. In at arcu nisi. Nam feugiat posuere mi
      eget iaculis. Aliquam volutpat lectus pretium dictum venenatis. Nulla congue maximus mauris in porttitor. Nullam non enim eget ante malesuada pharetra. Curabitur semper dui quam, vitae eleifend lectus tempus sit amet. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you should, however, add an else clause to take into account if the user scrolls back up again.. As it stands, the fixed class isn't readded when the scrollTop goes below 500