# Sticky Bootstrap Navbar not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar for a little test site I am working on and I need some help with it. I am using Bootstrap (as you can probably tell) but cannot figure out how to make my navbar stick to the top of the screen as you scroll down. I would like the navbar to stay beneath the jumbotron until you scroll to the point where it would normally go off the screen. When it starts to go off the screen I would like it to stay at the top of the screen but go back up when necessary. I have tried different code in JQuery files such as :

```
$('.navbar-default').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 50
  }
    });
```

If anybody is able to help, it would be much appreciated.

Below is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Hope's Seed</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/style.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class = "header">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Hope's Seed</h1>
    <p>You're Not Alone</p>
  </div>
</div>  

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>               
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="bg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/plantgrow.jpg">
    <div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS Code (there are likely some redundancies, I haven't gone back and cleaned it up yet):

```
.header .jumbotron {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#a1ff7c;
    font-family:Roboto Condensed;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #78c45a;
    border: 0px;
    font-family:Roboto Condensed;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: white; /*BACKGROUND color for active*/
    background-color: #78c45a;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover{
    background-color: #5a9344;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff; 
  background-color: #5a9344;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
    background-color:#5a9344;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color:#5a9344;;
}

p {
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
}

.bg .img-responsive {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.jumbotron {
    padding-top:1%;
    padding-bottom:1%;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
}

.jumbotron p {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.navbar-nav {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}

#myNavbar{
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed`?

Comment: changing to position:fixed makes my navbar go on the left side of the screen in a really awkward manner and is not what I'm looking for exactly. I want the navbar to stay in place until it starts to go off the screen, then I would like it to stay on top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a [**fixed Bootstrap navbar**](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), all you need to do is give the navbar a class of `navbar-fixed-top`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

I'm assuming you **also** want your green custom header to stick to the top of the screen, above the navbar. You'll also need to give the same class to that, in conjunction with giving the navbar a `top` offset equal to the height of the custom header:

```
<div class="header navbar-fixed-top">

.navbar.navbar-default {
  top: 155px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmn15zzr/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This works wonderfully. Is there a way I could make the header part stay at the top without the navbar going on top of anything? For example, it'll look like it does without the navbar-fixed-top class but once I start to scroll down to the point where the header is off the screen and the navbar is at the top, the navbar stays there unless you go back up where it'll stick back up to the top header part? Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Ahh, I think I know what you mean :) You'll need to use jQuery to calculate the height of the scroll, and then remove the class at that point. Something like `$(window).scroll(function() { if ($(document).scrollTop() > 155) { $('navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top'); } });`. You'll also need an 'else' condition to check that it's less than that: `else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 155)`. You'll have to play around with that a bit to get it looking nice though. See [this earlier answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42797360/2341603) for a bit more info :)

Comment: Sorry for pestering you, is there any way to make that top value responsive? I tried using %'s but it always resulted in a gap on smaller screen sizes.

Comment: Not pestering at all! Though you shouldn't be using a percentage-based values with a fixed header, as it goes against the entire reason behind having a fixed header; it should stay at the very top of the screen. The header size shouldn't change, so you shouldn't need a responsive `top` value. The header should never be made responsive in that regard :)

Comment: The top value, being what is keeping the navbar from being right on top of the header doesn't work on all small screen sizes. On larger ones, ~155px works but as you get smaller there appears to be some sort of gap between the two as the pixel amount is staying consistent.

Comment: What you need to ensure is that the header has a fixed height. You should explicitly tell it to have `height: 155px`. Just make sure those two values match up.

Comment: I set my height to that and the top value as well. There is no longer a gap between the two, but since the header is already resizing itself because it is in a jumbotron class, a white box starts to appear under it and grows larger depending on how small the screen size is because the jumbotron is responsive  (I think)...

Comment: Then take off the responsiveness of the jumbotron. The whole point of a fixed header is that it is **fixed**; not responsive :P